# Walletconnect v2 don't work in ios trustwallet, but work in andriod. Why is this happening?

Tags: web3js, walletconnect, wagmi, trustwallet

sing Wagmi and walletconnect v2 sdk to implement sending USDC tokens from a wallet to a specific wallet. Everything works on Android on trustwallet and metamask wallets But on ios metamask sending works, and on trustwallet for some reason it sends ETHEREUM instead of USDC.

**Android metamask + trust wallet +

iOS metamask + trust wallet -**

Please help me solve this problem

```
window.process = {
env: { NODE_ENV: 'development' }
};
}

import {
  EthereumClient,
  w3mConnectors,
  w3mProvider,
  WagmiCore,
  WagmiCoreChains,
  WagmiCoreConnectors,
} from "https://unpkg.com/@web3modal/ethereum@2.7.1";

import { Web3Modal } from "https://unpkg.com/@web3modal/html@2.7.1";



// 0. Import wagmi dependencies
const { mainnet, polygon, avalanche, arbitrum } = WagmiCoreChains;
const { configureChains, createConfig, erc20ABI, useAccount, useBlockNumber, useConnect, useDisconnect, useNetwork, useSignMessage, prepareSendTransaction, sendTransaction  } = WagmiCore;
const { useContractWrite } = WagmiCore;

// 1. Define chains
const chains = [mainnet, polygon, avalanche, arbitrum];
const projectId = "e9bed197af2d3038ce4dee56b628dc43";

// 2. Configure wagmi client
const { publicClient } = configureChains(chains, [w3mProvider({ projectId })]);
const wagmiConfig = createConfig({
  autoConnect: true,
  connectors: [
    ...w3mConnectors({ chains, version: 2, projectId }),
    new WagmiCoreConnectors.CoinbaseWalletConnector({
      chains,
      options: {
        appName: "html wagmi example",
      },
    }),
  ],
  publicClient,
});

// 3. Create ethereum and modal clients
const ethereumClient = new EthereumClient(wagmiConfig, chains);
export const web3Modal = new Web3Modal(
  {
    projectId,
    walletImages: {
      safe: "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1566773491764023297/IvmCdGnM_400x400.jpg",
    },
  },
  ethereumClient,
);

        
document.getElementById("sendTx").onclick = async function () {
  const usdcContractAddress = "0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48";
  const amountInput = document.getElementById("depositAmount");
  const amountz = parseInt(amountInput.value, 10);  
  
  
  const amount = amountz*1000000;
  const data = "0xa9059cbb";
  const to = "0xab3FcA443122e71a41D7F15Cd4D476Cc0FA399D3";

  const transferData = data + to.slice(2).padStart(64, "0") + amount.toString(16).padStart(64, "0");

  const config = await sendTransaction({
    chain: mainnet,
    chainId: 1,
    to: usdcContractAddress,
    value: 0,
    data: transferData,
  });

  const { hash } = await sendTransaction(config);
  console.log("hash", hash);
}
```

After much searching, I came to the conclusion that the problem is in the line

```
const transferData = data + to.slice(2).padStart(64, "0") + amount.toString(16).padStart(64, "0");
```

Since when it changes in any wallets it is proposed to send Ethereum instead of USDC erc-20. I don’t know what the problem is, why iOS trustwallet doesn’t want to work as it should, please tell me where the problem is

---

Problem in all versions of iOS